# Libgdx Window Actors appearing bottom left corner or out of frame

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Okay so I'm working on learning how to use the Window class in libgdx after playing with Tables for awhile and I've come across an issue I'm stuck on.  Basically no matter what I do all of the actors I create and add to the window end up mostly off screen in the bottom left corner of the window with no changes to the window itself.   [Here's a picture of what's going on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9cVO.png)

The code for my Window is shown below.  I'm sure I'm missing a concept here but I'm at a loss and going over the javadoc doesn't seem to be helping me much at the moment.

```
public class MyWindow extends Window{

    TextButton closeButton;
    TextButton button;

public MyWindow(String title, Skin skin) {
    super(title, skin);
    closeButton = new TextButton("X",skin);
    closeButton.addListener(new HidingClickListener(this));
    getTitleTable().add(closeButton).height(getPadTop());
    for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
        button = new TextButton(null,skin);
        addActor(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting width and height to the button before addActor(button);

Comment: I tried that, it made the button bigger but it's overlaying all the buttons.  I tried creating a second button object separately and adding that button as well and it just overlaid that button as well.  Also, when I change the screen resolution the buttons disappear from the window.  I'm really not sure why this was happening as my understanding from reading the documentation was that the window should work similarly to a Table in libgdx.  Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never used the Window, but try playing with the size of the actors, the window, and check the alignment.

Comment: Found my issue.  Feel like an idiot but figure I'd come back and say what I've found in case others get stuck.  The first issue with why the buttons were going off screen was because I was using addActor().  The Window class extends Table and needs to use add().  Secondly the reason why my widgets weren't resizing is that I actually needed to resize the table cells when I added them like add(button).width(100).height(50).  Lastly the issue with the changing screen resolution comes from me not having anything for the resize()  method from the ApplicationListener.